# Only prints out the first letter of each variable don't know why

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, masm

```
extrn ExitProcess:         PROTO
extrn WriteFile:           PROTO
extrn ReadFile:            PROTO
extrn GetStdHandle:        PROTO

mGetHandles             MACRO

    CONSOLE     equ     -11
    KEYBOARD    equ     -10

    mov rcx, CONSOLE            ;subsystem: console
    call GetStdHandle           ;handle in rax
    mov stdout, rax             ;save out handle
    mov rcx, KEYBOARD           ;keyboard code
    call GetStdHandle           ;handle in rax
    mov stdin, rax              ;save in handle

ENDM

mWriteConsole           MACRO

    mov pram, r12b             ;moves what is from the first

    mov rcx, stdout            ;parm1 = console handle          
    lea rdx, pram              ;parm2 = ascii message           
    mov r8, lengthof pram      ;length of what is in pram       
    lea r9, numWrite           ;store number of bits written        
    mov qword ptr [rsp+32], 0  ;parameter needed for write file     
    call WriteFile             ;display message


ENDM
mReadConsol             MACRO

    mov input, r12b            ;store value from main into input

    mov rcx, stdin             ;call keybord parm
    lea rdx, input             ;call input parm
    mov r8, lengthof input     ;length of input that accepts input
    lea r9, numRead            ;number of bits read
    call ReadFile              ;call read keyboard

    mov r12b, input            ;store input into r12 register to pass back

ENDM

.data
namProm     byte     'What is your name? '
addProm     byte     'What is your address? '
prompt      byte     'Nice to meet you,'
myName      byte     40 dup(0),0ah
address     byte     40 dup(0),0ah
newLine     byte     0ah

.data?
stdin       qword    ?
stdout      qword    ?
numWrite    qword    ?
numRead     qword    ?
pram        byte     ?
input       byte     ?


.code
mainCRTStartup      PROC

            sub rsp, 32                         ;reserve shadow space 
            push rbp                            ;save base pointer
            mov rbp, rsp                        ;make base ptr = stack ptr

            mGetHandles                         ;calls this macro to set stdin and stout

            mov r12b, namProm                   ;move namprom into r12 to pass to write console
            mWriteConsole                       ;calls mWriteConsole macro to display prom
            mov r12b, myName                    ;moves name into r12 regester to accept input
            mReadConsol                         ;calls read console to accept input
            mov myName, r12b                    ;moves input back into myname


            mov r12b, addProm                   ;move add prom into r12 to print prompt in write console
            mWriteConsole                       ;call write console to display prompt
            mov r12b, address                   ;move address into r12 to accept input from user
            mReadConsol                         ;call read consol to accept input
            mov address, r12b                   ;move input back into address

            mov r12b, prompt                    ;move prompt into regester to display prompt
            mWriteConsole                       ;call write console to display prompt

            mov r12b, myName                    ;move name into regester to display input name
            mWriteConsole                       ;call write console to display name


            mov r12b, address                   ;move address into regester to display the address
            mWriteConsole                       ;call write console


            pop rbp                             ;clears the base pointer
            add rsp, 32                         ;restors shadow space
            call ExitProcess                    ;returns to the c++ program
mainCRTStartup      ENDP
END
```

Comment: Presumably `mov r8, lengthof pram` does not work like you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

`pram` is a 1-byte "variable" declared with `pram        byte     ?`
`lengthof pram` is thus always 1, of course.

Use a debugger; you could have easily figured out that this was the problem and asked how to solve *that*.

Make your macro take a symbol name as an argument, or a `pointer, length`.

So you can do `mWriteConsole  addProm`.  And in that macro you can use `sizeof` in your macro to get the size in bytes of the static variable to be written to the console.

Comment: Thank you for the help